# Need SQL query to print count of month and year wise records from 2016 november to 2018 october in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Need SQL query to print count of month and year wise records from 2016 November to 2018 October in Oracle.

Example

Table xyz:

```
Count(*)| Mon-YYYY|
234440  | Nov-2016|
234443  | DEC-2016|
234445  | JAN-2016|
234446  | FEB-2016|
;
;
;
;
234446  | OCT-2018|
```

Comment: Did you write any code or try anything? Do you get any errors when trying to run SQL? Post sample data, table structures.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking & simply written (using Scott's EMP table as an example), that would be something like

```
select 
  to_char(hiredate, 'yyyy.mm') year_month,
  count(*)
from emp
where hiredate between date '2016-11-01' and date '2018-10-01'
group by to_char(hiredate, 'yyyy.mm')
order by to_char(hiredate, 'yyyy.mm');
```